# Transparent image control with resampling in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a form with a background image (painted on the form in Form1.Repaint).

**What I am a looking for:** A transparent image control, that can smoothly resize (resample) the loaded image.

(I need it to be transparent because the forms background image should be visible through)

**What I've tried:**

- **Standard TImage:** It's transparent, but it does not resample.
- **Graphics32 / Image32:** Resamples beautifully, but it's not transparent.

  I have googled for several hours now for fixes or work-arounds, but without much of a solution. This has nothing to do with the image loaded into Image32 being transparent, but instead the background color of the control still being white (white = the color-property of the Image32 control, and setting it to clNone does not work). [This is apparently as designed](http://graphics32.org/wiki/FAQ/AlphaTransparency)
- **GR32ex** (The GR32 Extension Components Pack), which supposedly adds a Transparent-property, however it has not been updated in many years, and I can not install it. It throws a gazillion errors on Delphi 2010 and Graphics32 v. 1.9.

Can anybody think of a solution or workaround? All I want is a control with transparency and resampling.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://code.google.com/p/gr32ex/ It's an GR32 Extension Components Pack...

Comment: @Andreas That's the 3rd bullet point in the question

Comment: I came across this thread in the graphics32 newsgroups that may be of interest: http://graphics32.org/news/newsgroups.php?art_group=graphics32.general&article_id=9505

Comment: @David Heffernan That's excellent! It works. That newsgroup actually came up during my troubleshooting earlier today, but I somehow disregarded it because it had, I think, unrelated code (I believe TMyShiftState has nothing to do with transparency?). But again: It works beautifully! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm surprised that `TImage32` doesn't do transparency. Are you really sure that is the case?

Anyway, if that is so, I would combine the transparency support of `TImage` with the re-sampling ability of `TBitmap32` to build a solution that way. Keep the original image in a `TBitmap32` instance. Whenever you need to load it into the `TImage` component, for example when re-sizing, use `TBitmap32` to perform an in-memory re-size and load that re-sized image.

In fact, if you are already painting the form's background yourself, why not paint the image yourself and simply do away with the image control?

**Update 1:** Websearch reveals a simple way to make TImage32 transparent: http://graphics32.org/news/newsgroups.php?art_group=graphics32.general&article_id=9505

**Update 2:** The link above is now dead, and the newsgroups can only be accessed via NNTP. I can't be 100% certain, but I think that the linked post was by Michael Haralabos and contained the following file:

```
unit GR32_ImageEx;

// Transparent TImage32 by Michael Haralabos

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, Classes, GR32_Image, GR32;

type
  TImage32Ex = class(TImage32)
  private
    FTransparent: Boolean;

    procedure SetTransparent(const Value: Boolean);
  public
    procedure ExecClearBackgnd(Dest: TBitmap32; StageNum: Integer); override;
  published
    property Enabled;
    property Transparent: Boolean read FTransparent write SetTransparent;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure TImage32Ex.ExecClearBackgnd(Dest: TBitmap32; StageNum: Integer);
var
  P: TPoint;
  SaveIndex: Integer;
begin
  if FTransparent and Assigned(Parent) and
     not (Assigned(Bitmap) and (BitmapAlign = baTile)) then
  begin
    SaveIndex := SaveDC(Dest.Handle);
    GetViewportOrgEx(Dest.Handle, P);
    SetViewportOrgEx(Dest.Handle, P.X - Left, P.Y - Top, nil);
    IntersectClipRect(Dest.Handle, 0, 0, Parent.ClientWidth, Parent.ClientHeight);
    Parent.Perform(WM_ERASEBKGND, Dest.Handle, 0);
    Parent.Perform(WM_PAINT, Dest.Handle, 0);
    RestoreDC(Dest.Handle, SaveIndex);
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TImage32Ex.SetTransparent(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FTransparent <> Value then
  begin
    FTransparent := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Graphics32', [TImage32Ex]);
end;

end.
```

Another topic here suggests that this may be what the now dead link referred to: [Delphi TImage32 - how to make the component invisible if no picture is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119152/)

Comment: yes the TImage32 container doesn't do transparency - this is by design.

Comment: Marked as answer. Thank you very much :) I appreciate it!

Comment: @David Heffernan I don't know if you still remember the simple way, but it would be great to add it or delete the link because it's dead.

Comment: @Triber Thanks. Serves me right for just posting the link. It will take me a while to get the content from the NNTP newsgroup. Please bear with me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, that's exactly what I needed, somehow I missed the second question.